# htaccess 301 redirect from old url to new url not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect from old url to new url using below code.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^restaurantDetails.php?resid=(.+)&resname=(.+)$ /restaurant/$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

But Its not working

or 
if I browse in address bar like below 
http://www.starmed.dk/restaurantDetails.php?resid=9&resname=demo-restaurant

then it will be redirect to
http://www.starmed.dk/restaurant/9/demo-restaurant

Any idea how to do this with an HTACCESS 301 redirect?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /restaurantDetails\.php\?resid=([^&]+)&resname=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /restaurant/%1/%2? [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^restaurant/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /restaurantDetails\.php\?resid=$1&resname=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Its redirecting to new url. But its shows 404 error. Please click this link then you can see the output
http://www.starmed.dk/restaurantDetails.php?resid=9&resname=demo-restaurant

Comment: Does the new url/path exist on your server?

Comment: yes, I've implemented like this.

#Search Details--------------------------------------------------------
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^resid=([^&]+)&resname=([^&]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^restaurantDetails.php$ /restaurant/%1/%2? [R=301,L]

#RewriteRule ^restaurant/([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)$ restaurantDetails.php?resid=$1&resname=$2 [NC,L]
#RewriteRule ^restaurant/([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/$ restaurantDetails.php?resid=$1&resname=$2 [NC,L]

Comment: Last 2 lines are my old implementaion. so I hided last 2 lines. Now I'm using your code only